# Mosquitto - disable subscription with wildcards

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'd like to disable subscritpion to all topics using wildcards (**+** and **#**), is it that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, on a per user basis. You can use the ACL to limit what topics a given user can subscribe to and these can include wildcards. Details of the ACL format can be found in the mosquitto.conf man page [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

You can also prevent anonymous users being able to connect to the broker at all.

```
allow_anonymous false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So including the acl_file can I prevent subscription to all topics using "#" wildcard? And usernames and passwords have to be configured in password_file? If so, is there a way to connect my database (with my users) to mqtt user list?

Comment: No, but you specify a suitable wildcard ACL for each user and if they do subscribe to # they will only see the topics that match the ACL

Comment: So using pattern in acl_file (like "pattern %u/topic_name") and "allow_anonymous false" in mosquitto.conf, no user can subscribe to #?

Comment: They can subscribe to `#` but they will only see messages that start `%u/topic_name`

Comment: Why is this correct answer currently at _-1_ ? - Upvoting this for the sake of sanity ;)